# How to record digital piano via USB cable?

Tags: digital-piano, audacity

I have found several similar topics however the solutions found there, seemed to be device/producer specific.

I have a digital piano: Roland GO:PIANO 88 and would like to record a play via USB A->B cable. I tried Audacity, however there is no option there to set the piano as input. It is visible by the program though:
[image]

Also, I don't have a microphone entry in my laptop, only the one for headsets. In device manager I see the piano only as sound controller, not as audio input:

[image]

Is there a way to make it work only with USB A->B cable? I am open to any other free software that works.

Many thanks!

Update 21/12/21. Adding photo of the back:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to record audio or MIDI? Do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: According to the [specifications](https://www.roland.com/global/products/gopiano_go-88p/specifications/), the USB port is not used for audio, but only for [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) (simply put, it's not an audio signal, is a protocol that allows to send messages that correspond to notes, just like a computer keyboard sends individual characters to the program, not spoken audio of what you're writing). But, that piano seems to support bluetooth audio, which ***might*** work with your computer, and ***theoretically*** can be used as an audio source.

Comment: @musicamante it supports Bluetooth as a receiver so that its speakers can be used for backing tracks from Bluetooth sources.

Comment: I want audio, not midi. As I understand midi would be only a sort of a transcript of notes.

Comment: In that case the only way I have is to record it via microphone?

Comment: @ojs Oh, I completely missed that aspect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To record audio from the keyboard, you need an audio interface with line inputs. When recording, you should connect the line outputs from the keyboard to the line inputs on the interface and the interface to the computer with USB.

Comment: I see, is there any specific audio interface that is compatible with my piano or any will do?

Comment: Anything with stereo line input will do. You'll probably need an adapter cable from 6.3mm stereo plug to two RCA or 6.3mm plugs, depending what connectors the interface you pick has.